# How does a device become SNMP-enabled?

Tags: snmp

I have a general question but I could not find any useful information to answer it.

Just to be clear, **I do understand how the SNMP works** (Manager, Agent, MIB).

**What I do not understand is how a device becomes SNMP enabled?**

Does it happen at the manufacturing stage?

Can anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Many devices support SNMP (routers, printers, switches etc.), What is the requirement? Also not all IP-based devices are SNMP enabled.

Comment: Someone wrote an implementation of the SNMP protocol into the software/firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SNMP is a protocol (set of rules) for device communications. An application on the device opens a network port, listens for connections, and responds to those connections. It's similar, at least in theory, to a web server or any other kind of server. Usually the SNMP server software will be written into firmware on the device by the manufacturer, but for computers it may be loaded at boot time or on demand.